# How do you add a boot entry to GRUB that redirects to your last booted entry?

Tags: boot, grub2

I was just wondering if it was possible to add a GRUB entry that when selected, automatically redirects you to your last booted entry. I looked in Grub Customizer, but there was nothing of interest. Closest thing was setting your last booted entry as the default, but my GRUB theme glitches out and it would be nice to have a specific entry used for booting up whatever you last used. I didn't try modifying the grub.cfg file because I don't know its syntax. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Update: I managed to fix it. As stated previously, the issue was with my GRUB theme, not GRUB itself. So I tried a different variant of the theme and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, set these entries is `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

Then run `sudo update-grub`